# How to remove selected color on drag over listview

Tags: android, listview

I am displaying a `ListView`. When I drag over it, the entire `ListView` is selected with a black background. How can I remove that black background?

Comment: From the Android developers' blog: [Why is my list black? An Android optimization](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html)

Answer (score 15):

just use in ur xml file inside ListView,

```
 android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 5):

It's probably because you have a custom background for your `ListView`. When you scroll those, the entire list gets highlighted in a black color due to its `cache color`.

Add this piece of code to your `ListView`and try again:

`android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`

Answer (score 3):

```
view.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
```

should be view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent) 
cause setBackgroundColor take a hex color value as parameter.

or

```
android:cacheColorHint = "#00000000"
```

use this tag for the your listView. or you can also use

```
listview.setCacheColorHint()
```

to set it programatically.

From [Why is my list black? An Android optimization](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html) on the Android developers' blog:

> To fix this issue, all you have to do is either disable the cache color hint optimization, if you use a non-solid color background, or set the hint to the appropriate solid color value. This can be dome from code or preferably from XML, by using the android:cacheColorHint attribute. To disable the optimization, simply use the transparent color #00000000. The following screenshot shows a list with android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" set in the XML layout file:

Answer (score 1):

use this,

```
yourList.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);
```